# Inserção de datas no PostgreSQL

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, sql-insert

Gostaria de saber como faço para configurar o `Postgre` a aceitar entradas de datas da seguinte forma: **"12122016"**.

Sei que com a mesma "grafia" é possível com YMD mais gostaria de saber como configurar para ele aceitar assim.

Desde já agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Se ficar 12/12/2016 resolve? A data vai depender do locale que você setar no banco, mas aí se for pt_br vai ficar assim com essa /. Não sei se tem como customizar do zero, quando eu preciso formatar costumo fazer isso no lado da aplicação.

Comment: Desculpe a demora pra responder, o ideal seria sem os caracteres separadores, pois estou lendo um arquivo de muitas linhas e gerando queries de insert apartir dele então dar um tratamento de um tipo especifico é impossível pois se tratam de muitos inserts de muitos tipos diferentes. Mesmo assim agradeço o palpite :)

Answer (score 1):

Willian,

O postgres possui o parâmetro `datestyle` que permite configurar o formato padrão de data do seu cluster (se configurado no postgresql.conf) ou do seu database (`ALTER DATABASE database_name SET datestyle TO "ISO, DMY";`), porém não localizei algo nesse formato ddMMyyyy, conforme seu exemplo. O padrão para esse parâmetro é: ISO, DMY

No entanto, ao realizar o INSERT você pode utilizar a função `to_date` para converter essa informação.

```
insert into nome_tabela (campo_data) values (to_date('12122016','ddMMyyyy'));
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: Desculpe a demora para responder, como falei mais acima eu estou gerando queries de inserts apartir de um arquivo de muitas linhas então da forma acima realmente daria certo porém, tratar um campo especifico aonde você está criando queries de muitas entidades diferentes é impossível. Mesmo assim obrigado por responder se não fosse esse meu cenário complicado rsrs daria como certa